# Subquery has too many columns; multiple selections in one select statement

Tags: sql, postgresql, psql

Disclaimer: Sorry if this is a simple question, or a badly worded question. I'm a noob and I didn't know how to word this problem, so I didn't know how to google it.

I have two tables. Math.question and Math.choice.

Math.question contains a questiontext column, as well as correctanswerid, wronganswerid1... and so on.

```
questiontext            correctanswerid     wronganswerID1    wronganswerid2
(question text          101                 102               103
  goes here)
```

Math.choice contains the id of the choice, and the choices text.

```
id     choicetext
101    (text goes here)
102    (text goes here)
...
```

I want to select questiontext from math.question, and the choicetext. so it'll show something like this:

```
questiontext     correctanswerText    wronganswer1text   wronganswer2text
(question text)  (choice text)        (choice text)      (choice text)
```

I have tried this:

```
select * from math.choice 
where id in (
    select CorrectAnswer_Choice_ID, Foil1_Choice_ID, Foil2_Choice_ID, Foil3_Choice_ID
    from math.question where id=301
);
```

I got the subquery has too many columns error. I'm not really sure where to go from here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need multiple `join`s.  Something like this:

```
select c.*, q1. choicetext, q2.choicetext, q3.choicetext
from math.choice c left join
     math.question q1
     on q1.id = c.CorrectAnswer_Choice_ID left join
     math.question q2
     on q2.id = c.Foil1_Choice_ID left join
     math.question q3
     on q3.id = c.Foil3_Choice_ID ;
```

Comment: Unfortunately I'm not home so I can't try this out. I'll mark this as answered when I get home :).  But this looks like it should work. For some reason I didn't think you could join the same table multiple times. Thanks!